# How can I tag video game music, like Shazam but for games?

Tags: audio-software

Are there any good online services or apps that can identify/tag music from video games?  I have tried using SoundHound, Google/Android music search, Shazam, etc., but they fail to find a match on game music that I have tried.

Whenever I search for game music tagging, major search engines like Google and Duck Duck Go just provide links to the traditional (non-game specific) tagging services.